# scrollIntoView not working on Chrome but perfeclty fine in Firefox

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I've encoutnered a problem concerning scrollIntoView. The code I wrote works on Firefox, but not on Chrome. I'am not getting any errors or anything from console therefore I don't know what's the problem. How to run it correctly on Chrome? I would like to solve it in Vanilla JS

Here's my code -> https://codepen.io/Rafi-R/pen/PLdvjO

```
const body = document.querySelector('body');
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
let section = 0;

const scrollDirection = e => e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -1 * e.deltaY;

const scrollToSection = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    section = 
        scrollDirection(e) < 0 
        ? (section + 1 >= links.length - 1 ? section = links.length - 1 : section + 1) 
        : (section - 1 <= 0 ? section = 0 : section - 1);   

    let element = document.querySelector(links[section].getAttribute("href"));
    scrollToTheView(element);
}

const scrollToTheView = el => {
    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    console.log(el, links[section].getAttribute("href"), section)
}

body.addEventListener('wheel', scrollToSection, { passive: false });
```

When codepen's console is open `console.log()` crashes `scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})`, thus scroll is not working.

Comment: I have default settings for both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but i had problems with `{ behavior: 'smooth' }`

Call just `scrollIntoView()`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what you're expecting to happen, but your codepen seems to work fine for me. After each scroll down of the mouse wheel the next section slides into view.

This is with Chrome 73.0.3683.86 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I expect section slide to the view exactly like you're saying. I'm working on Windows 7 Chrome v. 73.0.3683.86 and when scroll nothing happens :/

Comment: When removing`{ behavior: 'smooth' }` from scrollIntoView options, page jumps straight to given section. Something with that smooth beahvior must be causing some kind of bug...

Comment: @Rafał A bit late since you commented, but did you find a solution to make it work with { behavior: 'smooth' }?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't accept all the options in the `scrollIntoView` method. I faced the similar issue and found out if you change the values of these options it seems to be working fine.

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'end' });
```

Above snippet is working for me to scroll the element horizontally

[Refer the browser compatibility section in the MDN for `scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)